# Passing params in MVC Actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an typical MVC application that has the following Action:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string param1)
```

When I call this action this way:

```
http://domain/MyController/MyAction?param1=dasas
```

I receive param1 as supposed: "dasas"

But in MVC the idea is to pass params as following right?

```
http://domain/MyController/MyAction/dasas
```

This way it doesn't work and I am wondering why! Any idea?

UPDATE:
Here is my route:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: 
                new { 
                    controller = MVC.RegistrationAuthority.Name,
                    action = MVC.RegistrationAuthority.ActionNames.Landing, 
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional 
                });
```

Comment: On "But in MVC the idea is to pass params as following" - not necessary - it is up to you to decide what should be part of url and what should be passed as query parameters.

Comment: I think it is already answered in linked duplicate. When following suggestion in duplicate (same as Anthony Shaw's answer) make sure to properly order routes - more specific routes should go *before* more generic once like default (i.e. "/foo" before "/{controller}").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your route to know that he param being passed in is called `param1`

Out of the box asp.net mvc only figured for an `{id}` param

```
routes.MapRoute(null, "MyController/MyAction/{param1}", new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction"});
```

be sure to add this route before other routes that could potentially override it (i.e. the default route)

Comment: Is it not supposed to work with the default route (I updated the question)? I tried do add your code but it continues to come null

Comment: I changed the sequence of the rules, putting the more generic one in the end and it works. Anthony, your answer helped me.

Comment: yes, sorry. I should have been specific, your most generic route needs to come first